# AutoComplete Combobox Flex 3 to Flex 4 migration Issue

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flex4.5

We have been using the AutoCompleteModified.as (**Created by Jens Krause [www.websector.de]**) class in our project that was created using flex sdk 3, The AutoCompleteModified.as is an advanced version of comboxbox that has the autocomplete feature, Recently, we migrated sdk to flex 4.5 and faced compilation issues with **textInput.setSelection** and **textInput.selectionBeginIndex**, After thorough analysis, we replaced **textInput.setSelection**  with **textInput.selectRange** and **textInput.selectionBeginIndex** with **textInput.selectionAnchorPosition**, the compilation completed successfully but we started seeing strange behavior for combobox in application, when we type into combox, it always moves the curson to the leftmost position, causing it to type in reverse order.

Please advise/help to resolve this issue asap.

Comment: Do we have any solution for autocomplete combox for changing the cursor position. -- raja pusala